# Azure devops azure function app SAS url to aks docker container

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, devops, azure-aks

How to pass SAS url from function app to docker container deployed in AKS

I want this in automation because every time the new SAS url is creating when new changes made

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to create default overview dashboard as group by type in Azure Portal :**

Please follow the below steps to create a dashboard as a group type.

1.**Go to** [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/) > Click on the  **All resources** button on the left sidebar > Select **Pin blade**

[image]

To check the created dashboard in [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/).

Click on the **"Dashboards"** button on the left sidebar **>** under **"Dashboard section"** choose your dashboard, like below.

[image]

If you need only particular **Resource Group**, kindly follow the below steps.

Click on **setting** button and choose your resource group under resource group filter, like below.

[image]

Once modify the changes, it displays only **Resource Group** details.

[image]